# xsuaa error: The redirect_uri has an invalid domain

Tags: hana, cloudfoundry-uaa, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cloud-foundry

Considering my spring boot application and a simple web Page HTML both deployed with my no trial account in a CF without a custom domain. Both application works perfectly.
After adding a xsuaa service I see this error in the authorization step:

> The redirect_uri has an invalid domain.
> Authorization Request Error
> There was an error. The request for authorization was invalid.

To solve this error I try adding in the xs-security.json

```
"oauth2-configuration": {
    "redirect-uris": [
      "https://*.eu10-004.hana.ondemand.com"
    ]   }
```

Receiving same error, and using this uris:

```
"oauth2-configuration": {
    "redirect-uris": [
      "https://*.eu10-004.hana.ondemand.com/login/callback"
    ]   }
```

The auth process doesn't start and the HTML page communicate with spring boot correctly but without the auth step.

Where is the mistake and how can I solve or find consistent and update material?